# Bind ERB Template from more than one class

Tags: ruby, erb

I am trying to interpolate ERB template from multiple objects in Ruby. It works fine if the source of variables is one class. Whats the best way of doing the interpolation when the ERB contains variables present in different classes.

Here is a strip down version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'erb'
require 'pp'

class Person
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
  end

end

class Animal
  attr_reader :animal_type

  def initialize(type)
    @animal_type = type
  end

end

person = Person.new("John", "Doe")
animal = Animal.new("doggie")

template = "<%=first_name%> <%=last_name%> has a <%=type%>"

puts ERB.new(template).result(person.instance_eval { binding })
```

The above fail with `undefined local variable or method 'type'` which is correct, since that attribute belongs to object of Animal class.

One work around I have found is to create hashes and use merge to collapse them in to one, but that would be mean a lot of changes to the existing code. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use openstruct to make merging attributes a little more friendly so do don't have to rewrite your templates as much.

```
# in config/application.rb
require 'ostruct'

# in the file where you compile ERB
person = OpenStruct.new Person.new("John", "Doe").attributes
person.type = animal.type
```

With OpenStruct your object will be a hash but methods like `person.first_name` will still work. And you can add arbitrary key-vals, so you can make `person.type` return any value you want.

Comment: Thanks for a nice alternate. I'm not sure how scalable this would be if I'll have to write each hash attribute individually over. For example what if I had 10 attributes instead of 1 animal_type.

Comment: maybe `OpenStruct.new(person.attributes.merge(animal.attributes))`, but the problem is what if you have attributes named the same (like id or created_at).